# Is the second sentence correct? If not, how should I change it?

Tags: dates

> I would be available any time next Monday or Thursday. Please let me know if any of those dates work for you.

Comment: Which sentence are you concerned about, the first or second?

Comment: The second one.

Comment: You are not offering dates, but times in either of those dates. Please let me know which time slot works for you.

Comment: What makes you think it might not be correct? It's a perfectly normal sentence that has been said millions of times.

Comment: Keep it simple: "When would you like to meet?"

Comment: Also, I'd say "I will" rather than "I would".